# How to nofollow several links in a page with the same extention?

Tags: hyperlink, meta, nofollow

I have several links like this: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/visit/xxxxxxx

Is there a way to make them all nofollow using the /visit/ word?

I want to be able to do this to all the links that I have already, all together, not one by one.

Tks!!

Comment: What programming language are you using? c#, php or ?

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way

```
$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (strpos($actual_link , '/visit/') !== FALSE)
    print("<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"nofollow\" />");
```

Comment: Typically tour theme has a header.php file. Then place it inside the Head-element